# jsonを使わず、stringで複数の画像を保存する方法がわかりません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

１つの選択ダイアログで、複数の写真をアップロードしたいと考えています。(今jsonが使える状態ではないので、stringのカラムで実装したいと考えています。)しかし、この場合でのcontrollerのカラムの保存の仕方がわからない状態です。
もしわかる方がいらしたら、どうぞ教えていただきたいです。

```js
db

  add_column :plans, :image, :string
```

```css
controller
 
  def create
    Plan.create(image: params[:image])
  end

  private

  def plan_params
    params.permit(:image)
  end
```

```html
view new

  <%= file_field_tag 'image', :multiple => true %>
```

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるのでは？ [rails carrierwaveで複数ファイルアップロードができない](https://teratail.com/questions/93425)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/170945